# I need some help understanding LINQ group by

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Movie
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
```

and a text file of movies, that'll be parse into a list

```
The_Godfather Action 96
The_Dark_Knight Drama 24
Cleopatra Comedy 61
Sabotage Action 88
Inception Drama 86
The_Matrix Comedy 14
Life_Is_Beautiful Drama 19
City_of_God Horror 12
Raven Comedy 30
Breaking_Wind Comedy 59
City_Lights Documentary 46
Born_Wild Drama 55
```

and a function

```
 public static Dictionary<string, Movie> HighestRatingForEachGenre(List<Movie> movies)
```

<strike>I want to return the highest rating for each genre using LINQ.</strike>

I want to group by genre then return a title and movie object for each genre.

I could do this with a foreach loop easily.

I'm still new to LINQ and have no idea where to look.

basic approach

```
            Dictionary<string, Movie> result = new Dictionary<string, Movie>();
            foreach (Movie movie in movies)
            {
                if (result.ContainsKey(movie.Genre))
                {
                    if (result[movie.Genre].Rating < movie.Rating) result.Remove(movie.Genre);
                    else continue;
                }
                result.Add(movie.Genre, movie);
            }
            return result;
```

Comment: Your function name is not quite a match for your return type. Do you want the *highest rating for each genre* as a `Dictionary<string, int>` or the *top movie for each genre* as a `Dictionary<string, Movie>`?

Comment: I want a string, movie return. Essentially give me the title and give me the whole object of that title. I'll parse for the rating for that title myself through the object. 
I know that's not efficient, but that's what it's asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired results, your LINQ expression needs to do three things in succession:

1. Group the movies by Genre
2. Extract the top movie from each group
3. Map the resulting collection to a dictionary.

The first step is to group the movies by Genre, which can be done with `movies.GroupBy(m => m.Genre)`. This will yield a collection of groups, where each group has (1) Key = the common Genre and (2) a collection of movies sharing that Genre. The `m => m.Genre` part is a *lambda function* that selects which property defines the desired groupings.

Next, within each group, you want to select to top rated movie. This can be done with a combination of `Select(...)`, `.OrderBy(...)`, and `.First()`. as in `.Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(m => m.Rating).First())`.

Finally, `.ToDictionary(...)` can build a dictionary of the results, specifying `m => m.Genre` as the dictionary key selector.

Putting all that together gives:

```
var highestRatingForEachGenre = movies
    .GroupBy(m => m.Genre)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(m => m.Rating).First())
    .ToDictionary(m => m.Genre);
```

(The last two lines can actually be combined in a more advanced form of the `.ToDictionary()` function, but I believe separate steps is easier to read and understand.)

The above uses LINQ *method syntax* to perform the operations. The same can also be done using LINQ *query syntax*. (I much less often so can't provide a quick example off the top of my head.)

I suggest that you read the documentation for each method used so that you understand how the above works.

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of the groups. Each group is itself an `IEnumerable<T>` of the elements in the group, and each group also has a `Key` - the value that identifies each group. This is the property by which you are doing the grouping.

The enumerable sequence of groups can be turned into the dictionary you want by using [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-todictionary-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-collections-generic-keyvaluepair((-0-1)))))), with the group's key as the key, and the movie with the maximum rating in that group. To get the movie with the maximum rating, you can use [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-7.0) in .NET 6+.

```
Dictionary<string, Movie> HighestRatingForEachGenre(List<Movie> movies) =>
    return movies.GroupBy(x => x.Genre)
               .ToDictionary(
                   g => g.Key, // dictionary's key is the group's key
                   g => g.MaxBy(m => m.Rating) // dictionary's value is computed like this
               );
```

Comment: on a related note, if your real list comes from SQL Server database, as opposed to file that you are loading into memory, `MaxBy` is not yet supported. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25566

Answer (score -1):

I would tweak @T N's answer just a little bit:

```
var highestRatingForEachGenre  = movies.GroupBy(s => s.Genre).Select(s => new
{
    s.Key,
    MaxRating = s.Max(r => r.Rating)
}).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.MaxRating);

foreach (var movie in x)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Highest rating in {movie.Key} is {movie.Value}" );
}
```

combining  `OrderBy` and `First` into a single `Max` call

Comment: Actually TN's answered it. The return type is string, movie yours is string, int
But thank you regardless for helping.

Comment: TN's answer actually answers the question as I understood it. This just finds the largest number for each genre.

Comment: my tweak is replacing two functions `grp => grp.OrderByDescending(m => m.Rating).First()` with simple `Max(r => r.Rating)`

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `grp => grp.OrderByDescending(m => m.Rating).First()` does then. It orders the movies from highest rating to lowest and then returns the first movie (i.e. the one with the highest rating from that grouping). `grp.Max(r => r.Rating)` returns the highest rating (number). With TN's answer, OP can achieve what they want: find the movie with the highest rating from each genre. With your code, they can only tell what the highest rating was for each genre, though they don't know which movie that rating belongs to.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - I don't think I misunderstand the difference. OP stated "I want to return the highest rating for each genre" - not which movie it belongs to ;)

Comment: I understood it as "the highest rating [movie] for each genre" after reading their current non-LINQ code. They've also clarified that they do want the movies themselves in a subsequent [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76577839/i-need-some-help-understanding-linq-group-by/76577973?noredirect=1#comment135017395_76577839).

Comment: The return type is  Dictionary<string, Movie>. So a Dictionary containing a string (title) and the Movie object. Yes the question title is misleading. Apologies